# Managing separate in-development and usable copies of app

Tags: xcode, version-control

I have an app I am working on that I would like to use in my everyday life, but it's always being developed on, so I never get the chance to use it.

I cycle from the "ready" stage to the "developing" stage and back and forth. Is there a way I can maintain two versions in Xcode, one being "development", and the other being "ready to use", but still using somewhat the same code?

Comment: Just create another Target for `ready`. Here is a [Tutorial](http://hariniachala.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/creating-multiple-targets-in-ios.html) for how to create a new Target.

Comment: @EricQian maintaining two build targets for constantly changing versions of the same code can be time consuming, error prone, and cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the purpose of good version managment software. Using git (included in dev tools) or mercurial you can branch the code at each release. This allows you to continue development on the new branch and restore to the stable version whenever needed. When a new release is stable, merge the branch and create a new development branch. Make sure you change the bundle identifer of your xcode projects in the development branch so that you can have both apps installed on a device at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a version control system? This is a classic case for a good branching model. Go get a github (or similar) account and if you need to keep your code private you can pay rather than use the free service.

The point of the VCS is that you can branch your code. This means that you can have a production ready version (the one you use every day) and your development version (the one you are constantly working on). When you are done with a new feature, you merge it with your production version.

Since it's really easy to start and well documented I'd suggest:
This VCS...
http://github.com

This branching model...
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

This git client:
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score -1):

Why do all this mess when if your app is already on the App Store use a promo code to have on your device the App to use for all the time ... ;-)